# object file built for free standing (BlackBerry Dynamics iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

I'm having trouble to build an external pre built dependency. It throws the following error:

```
In /Users/me/Projects/app/ThirdParty/GoodFiles/GD.framework/GD(nondga_helper.o), building for iOS, but linking in object file built for free standing, file '/Users/me/Projects/app/ThirdParty/GoodFiles/GD.framework/GD' for architecture arm64
```

One of the questions that really bothers me is that I don't have a real idea what "free standing"  really means. I thought it had to do with being a fat binary, but after running `lipo -thin arm64 GD -o GD` (and verifying with `-info` that it really worked) in one of my build scripts I'm still seeing the same problem.

I also tried to exclude arm64 from the simulator and x86_64 from iOS builds in Excluded Architectures as mentioned elsewhere, but that didn't work either.

---

Removed the Xcode 12 reason. This already doesn't compile anymore in Xcode 11.

Comment: Wow, Googling "building for iOS, but linking in object file built for free standing" this is the only result I get. That feels pretty lonely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check:

Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools

In my case it was set to Xcode 12 after installing Xcode 12. There is NO Xcode 12 proof solution until mid December.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are new BB certification files you have to add along with the usual GD.Framework files. These are documented on Blackberry website

New Xcode build system

```
GD.framework
BlackBerryCerticom.xcframework
BlackBerryCerticomSBGSE.xcframework
```

Legacy Xcode build system

```
GD.framework
BlackBerryCerticom.framework
BlackBerryCerticomSBGSE.framework
```

https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios/8_1/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios-devguide/Steps-to-get-started-And-iOS/rqx1490022241984/Prepare-an-app-to-use-the-static-framework

Comment: Are you sure this works for the Xcode 12 build system?

Comment: for xcode12 the xcfamework files should allow it to build.